# How to Get data (token) from dev tools and put it in fetch Post

Tags: javascript, html

How can i easily get data via dev tools and put it in fetch? I would like to send a request post via the console, unfortunately I can't find a way to correctly copy this token. I tried queryselector but unfortunately fetch instead of searching for such a token, it sends the function name as body. Unfortunately I cannot find the answer

```
fetch(url, {
  "headers": {
   
  "referrer": url
  "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
  "body": "
token=document.querySelector("meta[name=token]")",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

Comment: huh? dev tools is not something accessible to your web page

Comment: that code is invalid `"token=document.querySelector("meta[name=token]")"` you should be seeing errors in your console

Comment: yes i know there is an error. I would like to know if there is a solution available

Comment: write valid code for a start - not sure why you'd post that code, knowing it's invalid, and not mention it, and ask how to get something from dev tools!

Comment: that was just an example

Answer (score 0):

If you have an easy way to have your data as a js object, you would need to do something like this:

```
const data = {call whatever function return the body in a js object format};
// For instance const data = {welcomeText: 'Hello', userName: 'World'};
fetch(url, {
  "headers": {/* insert the correct headers here, probably need 'Content-Type': 'application/json' */},
  "referrer": url
  "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
  "body": JSON.stringify(data), // here pass the data as query
token=document.querySelector("meta[name=token]")",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

But knowing what the data format, or how you expect it to be formatted would make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: I copied the post request to fetch. I have all the data to resend it, but one token value is time dependent and changes every minute. I can manually override this token, but I'd like to do it automatically. document.querySelector ("meta [name = token]"). content + h () This query correctly displays the token value to me in the console, but I would like fetch to automatically insert it when it is sent

Comment: Then you need h to be available as a window variable. Then the body could be `\`token=${document.querySelector('meta[name="token"]').getAttribute('content') + h()}\``  (supposing that your selector is correct and the token is in the content attribute of your meta tag)